# How can I open chests I can't bounce on?

Tags: ducktales-remastered

[image: Chests on the ceiling]

As you can see here, there are 2 chests at the top of the screen, which I can't bounce on, and I can't hit with my cane. How can I open these chests and get the treasure inside?

Comment: In the original game, I remember having to hit them by knocking objects off the floor diagonally upwards using the "golf swing" move.

Comment: @agent86 looks like that is probably the right answer. I stomped a few blocks out here, which probably should have been used for that. If you want to submit it as an answer, I'll accept :)

Comment: Works fer me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in these scenarios, there are blocks on the ground that you can stand next to.  When you move against them, you should be given the option to "golf swing" them diagonally upward.  This will open the chest and drop the loot.

Unfortunately, if you break these blocks without knocking them upwards, you'll miss out on the opportunity to open these chests.